# Is there a safety system to prevent overheating?

Tags: overheating

Is there currently a system in place that prevents overheating. I have recently been having issues with my mobile hotspot and I noticed that the issues I have seem to be when the phone is above 90 degrees F. (Using a battery temperature app).

When the phone is room temperature everything seems to work fine and when it is above 90 I seem to have issues. I thought maybe the wifi chip was having issues, so I manually tethered with USB and continued to have issues. To rule out my laptop, I connected the phone to my router and hardwired in my laptop. I then bought another cell phone which had the same issues. Specifically the issue I was having was full 20 Mbps and then 0 and then 20 and then 0. (Tested with speedtest.net multiple times.) So it appears to be the actual chip that connects to the cell towers. (On both phones it was doing this.)

Is there a safety mechanism in place in the android system that detects that your phone is heating up and begins cycling chips on and off to prevent overheating? I can see how for most activities a normal person wouldn't notice unless you're streaming something live with no buffer (ie: remote desktop over hotspot). Actually if it does this it would be almost genius because it wouldn't need to completely power off. It could just cycle between normal power and lower power which wouldn't be an issue for 95% of the things you do, it would increase battery life and decrease phone temperature. However, I also would be doing the 5% of the tasks were it is annoying as all get out watching the mouse cursor skip across my screen and watching windows minimize robotically with jerking updates.

Comment: i can't answer your question but i got the feeling that [app](https://github.com/Grarak/KernelAdiutor/releases/download/v0.9.10.1/stable-v0.9.10.1.apk) might be helpful to figure out (there is also a temperature watchdog for qualcomm chipset, not sure if related)

Comment: CPUs have usually a built in thermal throttling system that reduces the frequency and the used voltage if the CPU gets too hot.